# Inotifywait not working on /var/log directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu-mate, inotify

This sets up the watches, but no log files are created. Is that because var/log is root?

```
 #!/bin/bash
    # Ubuntu_Mate 18.04 LTS
    # Does NOT work Maybe because directory is root owned ??
    # Use of inotifywait to monitor files in /var/log/
    
    #Either issue ps -ef | grep inotifywait, pick the PID (in your example presumably 7341) and then send it a signal:
    #kill 7341
    
    Monitored_Directory=/var/log/
    
    inotifywait -m "$Monitored_Directory" --format '%w%f' -e create -e delete -e moved_to -e moved_from |
        while read file; do
            date +'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' >> /home/andy/Downloads/New_Created_Files.txt
            echo New file downloaded OR created. >> /home/andy/Downloads/New_Created_Files.txt
            gxmessage -fg red -font  'sans 25' -timeout 3 ' File has been created,deleted, or moved to/out of the specified directory.'
        done
    #killall inotifywait
    
    # To find instances of inotify  
    #    ps -p $(find /proc/*/fd/* -type l -lname 'anon_inode:inotify' -print 2> /dev/null | sed -e 's/^\/proc\/\([0-9]*\)\/.*/\1/')
```

Comment: I would expect that file creation, deletion or movement operations only occur if log rotation takes place which typically happens once a day or if a log is getting too big.

Comment: Thanks. I added -e modify.